# MATLAB Surf plot with bins

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, bins

I have a `nxm` matrix where `n` is the number of bins in the `x axis` and `m` is the number of bins in the `y axis`. Each position in the matrix has a number which shows how many data points are in matching `x-y` bin ranges from my raw data and when surf plotted results in a density plot.

The problem is if I have `100 x-bins` and `50 y-bins` the axis of my surf plot will be `0-100` on the `x-axis` and `0-50` on the `y-axis`. Which makes sense because I am doing `surf(Matrix)`.

But infact I want the `x` and `y axis` to be from `0-5` for example. Therefore the number of bins for `x` and `y` will determine only the resolution of the plot. `Low number of bins = low resolution`. `High number of bins = high resolution`. When for the whole time the axis of the plot are `0-5`.

In a nutshell is it possible to plot a matrix of varying size that is used for a surf plot into pre-assigned axis values?

(Of course doing `axis([0 5 0 5])` will not work)

Found it difficult to word the question but hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understood your question, but are you referring to using given x- and y-axis values to display in the plot? Something like `x = linspace(xmin, xmax, 100); y = linspace(ymin, ymax, 50); surf(x,y, Matrix)` where `xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax` are the min/max values for your data? You can set these to whatever values you want for the plot.

Comment: Yes to the first point :) I am not familiar with linspace function but I will look it up in 'help' and let you know how that works!

Comment: Great. `linspace(x1, x2, N)` creates a vector of `N` evenly spaced values between `x1` and `x2`. Of course, you can replace the vectors generated this way by any that are appropriate for your data and locations of your bins as long as the sizes match those of your `Matrix`.

Comment: Wonderrrfuulll!!!!  Works a treat! :D